# Help needed for mod_rewrite / url rewrite expression

Tags: iis, url, url-rewriting

i m newbie in URL  rewriting.. frankly speaking i have no idea bout using regexp
Here is what i want to do .. 
i want a url rewrite rule for

www.mydomain.com/news/this is new title/1

this shud call/go to

www.mydomain.com/news/display.asp?id=1

similarly

www.mydomain.com/articles/this is article title/1

shud call/go to

www.mydomain.com/article/display.asp?id=1

I guess. both the above patterns can be done in via one rule

I will be using ISAPI_Rewrite Lite (FREE) add on for enabling my IIS server for IIS rewrite.. http://www.helicontech.com/

This is sample rewrite url rule i got from the documentation .. hope this helps u

```
RewriteRule (.*?\.asp)(\?[^/]*)?/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(.*) $1(?2$2&:\?)$3=$4$5
```

Answer (score 0):

got the solution .. but not sure if this the best approach ..

I had to write 2 rules in order to handle urls without trailing slash. If u know how to combine them then plz reply

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/$ $1/details.asp?mod_id=$3 [NS,I]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ $1/details.asp?mod_id=$3 [NS,I]
```